# How do I schedule a task to run at very long periodic intervals

Tags: java

I am using void java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) to execute a task at specified "period". 
I want to specify a period which is quite large - the period which is **larger then max long** value. i want to use double value to specify the period.
Can anyone help me to do is?
Is there any other possible way to execute the task at interval which is very long period.
Thanks

Comment: How big is the period exactly?

Comment: Longer that Long.MAX_VALUE? The sun might have exploded before your task runs (actually maybe not, Long.MAX_VALUE milliseconds are only 292 million years)...

Comment: yes its my mistake.
I was calculating repeat period in wrong way.
(7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 5 results in negative value.
After typecasting the answer to long it works fine. 
(long)5 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 gives correct value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its my mistake.
I was calculating repeat period in wrong way.
(7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 5 results in negative value.
After typecasting the answer to long it works fine. 
(long)5 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 gives correct value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your not providing enough information on your intent - what lengths of periods are we talking about? Days, months, years?

I suspect your using the wrong tool here. For job scheduling I'd look at something like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) as it support [cron-like](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) scheduling where you can specify a schedule in seconds/minutes/hours/days/years.